# Unable to connect with Azure Container Services - Kubernetes

Tags: azure, kubernetes, credentials, microservices, azure-container-service

I am working on setting up environment for deploying microservices.

I have gotten as far as building my code and deploying to a registry but having problem running it in Azure Container Services.

I am following this guide to connect to ACS: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-service/container-service-connect

But i fail on the step: Download Cluster Credentials
Using the given command

```
az acs kubernetes get-credentials --resource-group=<cluster-resource-group> --name=<cluster-name>
```

Ofc changing the reseource group and clustername to the correct names from my portal. I get an error:

```
[WinError 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context
```

(if i change resource group or clustername to something else I get other errors so seems it can find those at least)

When i try to search for the error it seems to be some IP adress problem but can't figure out what to do. Tried running same command from other network (from home) to make sure work firewall is not blocking something.. but I get the same error

Any help appriciated!

Comment: try redeploying the cluster?

Comment: No.. Have not considered redeploying the cluster. You think it could help? I don't know what I would do different in the deployment process that would help this issue.

Comment: you don't do anything different, but sometimes k8s clusters gets deployed and is broken from the very start, so try redeploying...

Comment: @Swippen The command is no problem. I suggest you could check whether you could ssh to master VM.

Comment: @Swippen Please ensure you could ssh to master VM and download the credentials.

Comment: Also, do you have the latest `az` version?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I will try ssh to master VM and check az version (pretty sure its latest since i recently installed it) and check back on how it goes. Also whoever downvotes, pls comment why so I can improve my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This command copy the cluster credentials to your machine. Background processes are ssh to your cluster VM and copy the credentials.

So, **you should ensure you could ssh to the master VM manual**. If you could not ssh to master VM manual, `az` command also could not do it. You could get your `master-dns-name` on Azure Portal.

```
ssh -i id_rsa <user>@<master-dns-name>
```

Notes: If `az` command does not work and you could ssh to master VM, you could download credentials to your machine. They are same. You could check your [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-service/container-service-connect#connect-to-a-kubernetes-cluster) about this.

You also need check your azure cli version. You could use the following commands

```
az --version
```

My version is 2.02. It works for me.

Comment: Could you check your `az --version` version? My version is `2.0.2`. It works  for me.

Comment: There have been a bit of a paus in the project so have not had the time to check yet. Promise I will check and if I get good information to continue accept the answer otherwise give feedback on the result.

Comment: I had version 2.0.0 of the Azure CLI. After upgrading python (ran into some pip problems) and az to latest (2.0.3) I got rid of the above problem in this question. I have after that ran into some connection timeout issues but that is most likely due to some firewall restrictions so not related. @Walter Pls add the azure cli version to the answer and I will accept.

Comment: OK. I have added it to answer.